# Redirect to specified page when insufficient permissions?

Tags: theme-development, redirect

I am using a plugin to allow users access to specific posts, but for restricted users, it shows:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

How can I redirect restricted users to a specified page when it shows this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the direct answer to your problem. I personally believe that even if it possible it might not be wise to do it the way you want to do it. If you know a little programming then you can use the following one page plugin to achieve what you want.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Limit User Access To Pages
 */
defined('ABSPATH') or die("No script kiddies please!");
function RestrictPageAccessToUsers()
{
    /**
     * Global Intializations
     */
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    global $post;

    /**
     * @var array $usersToRedirect Contains user IDs that 
     * should be restricted to enter $pageToRestrict
     */
    $usersToRedirect = array(2, 3);

    /**
     * @var array $pagesToRestrict Contains post (page) IDs 
     * that should be restricted for $usersToRedirect
     */
    $pagesToRestrict = array(14);

    /**
     * @var string $redirectUrl Contains link where the user 
     * should be redirected if it is not allowed to access 
     * the page.
     */
    $redirectUrl = home_url();

    if (in_array($current_user->ID, $usersToRedirect) === true && in_array($post->ID, $pagesToRestrict) === true) {
        wp_redirect( $redirectUrl );
        exit();
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'RestrictPageAccessToUsers' );
```

There are three things that you need to configure in this plugin. These are:-

```
$usersToRedirect
$pagesToRestrict
$redirectUrl
```